# GeckoDocument.CreateEvent throws an exception

Tags: c#, mozilla, gecko

I have a GeckoFX 29 GeckoWebBrowser in my C# application.
I navigate successfully to a webpage and I have an element that doesn't accept a simple "click()" and so I have to forcefully dispatch events. 
The problem is that when I try to create the event the GeckoFX core throws an exception.

```
var eventName = "mouseover";
var domEvent = browser.DomDocument.CreateEvent(eventName);
domEvent.DomEvent.InitEvent(new nsAString(eventName), true, true);
```

The exception is thrown at CreateEvent(eventName) and the exception is this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80530009): Exception from HRESULT : 0x80530009
   at Gecko.nsIDOMDocument.CreateEvent(nsAStringBase eventType)
   at Gecko.nsString.GenericPass[T,TString](Func`2 func, String value) in c:\Users\micro_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\geckofx-29.0\Geckofx-Core\nsString.cs:line 221
   at Gecko.nsString.Pass[T](Func`2 func, String value) in c:\Users\micro_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\geckofx-29.0\Geckofx-Core\nsString.cs:line 476
   at Gecko.GeckoDomDocument.CreateEvent(String name) in c:\Users\micro_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\geckofx-29.0\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs:line 155
   at MyApp.Window.createEvent(GeckoDocument doc, String eventName)
```

I tried to look into the source code, but nsIDOMDocument is just an interface and there is no other information available for this issue that I can find.

Comment: Is the `google-chrome` tag a mistake?  This seems to relate strictly to Mozilla/Gecko.

Comment: looking around the repository of GeckoFX I found something related to chrome and I thought I should add the tag as well...

Comment: Probably a reference to "chrome" in the generic sense of an application's user interface.  Now if only I could help with your question...

Comment: Updated the post with something that might not be related. I hope it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that CreateEvent accepts only a few strings. 
Because it didn't work I was trying to dispatch the events by calling a java script that I was going to insert in the document. Researching that I noticed that CreateEvent was used with the parameter "Events" and then you would init your event with the actual event name.

So far I found out that params that work with CreateEvent are "Events", "MouseEvent", "KeyboardEvent".

This code works:

```
var eventName = "mouseover";
var domEvent = browser.DomDocument.CreateEvent("MouseEvent");
domEvent.DomEvent.InitEvent(new nsAString(eventName), true, true);
```